# How do I customise the images/descriptions for links that I add to a Stack in Delicious?

Tags: delicious

I've added the site (see here: https://del.icio.us/url/d27948bf7c7978a716c74045ce60249f), but would like their logo and description to be displayed, not the contents of their latest post.